# How to create a CSV string from a Generic List<T>

Tags: c#, generics

i have the following code to return a list of generics that i want to iterate through and as a result generate a comma separated list of values as a string.

```
public static List<ReportCriteriaItem> GetCurrentSelection(ReportWizardCriteriaType criteriaType)
    {
        return Criteria.CriteriaList.FindAll(delegate(ReportCriteriaItem item) 
                                                { return item.CriteriaType == criteriaType; }
                                            );
    }
```

here is the definition for ReportCriteriaItem - the object i make a generic list out of... i think this is the key here, to get its "id" field into a CSV:

```
public class ReportCriteriaItem
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("type")]
    public ReportWizardCriteriaType CriteriaType { get; set; }

    public ReportCriteriaItem() { }
    public ReportCriteriaItem(ReportWizardCriteriaType criteriaType, string id, string name, string value)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
        this.CriteriaType = criteriaType;
    }
}
```

can i use a for each loop to do this?

Comment: Hope nobody minds the title change... a little more indicative of the actual question.

Comment: Lol... there needs to be a Mexican standoff tag ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string list = "";
foreach (ReportCriteriaItem item in GetCurrentSelection(...)) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(list)) list += ",";
    list += item.???;
}
// do something with the list.
```

Comment: Take in count that if the field contains a `,`, that won't work.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest approach is to use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c.aspx):

```
string joined = string.Join(",", GetCurrentSelection(...).Select(x => x.Value));
```

The exact details of what you do will depend on which version of C# and .NET you're using, but the above is just an example. If you can give us more details, we can give you more specific code.

(In particular, in .NET 3.5 you'll need to provide `string.Join` with an array; in .NET 4 you don't need to. The version of .NET you're using is much more important than the fact that you're using ASP.NET.)

Comment: i am using .net 4.0 but its not liking that i try to join a GENERIC list, ideas?

Comment: using: var csv = String.Join(",", GetCurrentSelection(criteriaType).ToArray() ); im told i have invalid arguments...?

Comment: @kalapy: If you're really using. Net 4 then that should be fine even without the call to ToArray - but note that it will call ToStrung on each value. Is that what you want? If not, use a projection as per my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have the list, then you can just use the [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) method:

```
var myList = GetCurrentSelection(ReportWizardCriteriaType.SomeCriteria);
var csv = String.Join(",",myList.ToArray());
```

Voila!

Comment: Whoops! Realized I had my params backward... fixed now

Answer (score 2):

If you have .net 4, you can use [String.Join<T>(string, IEnumerable<T>)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx):

```
string csv = string.Join(", ", GetCurrentSelection(...));
```

The string items are generated from `ReportCriteriaItem` by executing `ToString()` on them. If the string value must be generated by accessing some other method or property of your ReportCriteriaItem (or if you are using a .net version smaller than 4), [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196952/asp-net-c-iterate-a-generic-list/4196991#4196991) is the way to go.

Comment: i have one issue: var csv = String.Join(",", GetCurrentSelection(criteriaType) );  does not like that i am trying to join a GENERIC list not an array.

Comment: @kacalapy: That's strange; it should work in 4.0. I cannot test it right now, unfortunately, since I don't have Visual Studio available...

Answer (score 1):

i like the join one line solutions but due to the nature of the beast, and the beast being my object i have to loop and pull the value of each generic item...

```
string csv = "";
            foreach (ReportCriteriaItem item in GetCurrentSelection(criteriaType))
            {
                csv += item.Id + ",";
            }
            return csv.TrimEnd(",".ToArray() ) ;
```

Comment: easy way of removing the last ','. Always annoys me to have the if in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy!

```
public static class DataHelper
{
   public static string ToCsv<T>(string separator, IEnumerable<T> objectlist)
   {
                Type t = typeof(T);
                PropertyInfo[] fields = t.GetProperties();

                string header = String.Join(separator, fields.Select(f => f.Name).ToArray());

                StringBuilder csvdata = new StringBuilder();
                csvdata.AppendLine(header);

                foreach (var o in objectlist)
                    csvdata.AppendLine(ToCsvFields(separator, fields, o));

                return csvdata.ToString();
            }

public static string ToCsvFields(string separator, PropertyInfo[] fields, object o)
            {
                StringBuilder linie = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (var f in fields)
                {
                    if (linie.Length > 0)
                        linie.Append(separator);

                    var x = f.GetValue(o);

                    if (x != null)
                        linie.Append(x.ToString());
                }

                return linie.ToString();
            }
    }
```

Use it like this

```
var customers = new List<Customer>(); // Any simple class
string csv = DataHelper.ToCsv(";",customers );
```